# Weighted Training Examples in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, statistics, neural-network

Given a set of training examples for training a neural network, we want to give more or less weight to various examples in training. We apply a weight between 0.0 and 1.0 to each example based on some criteria for the "value" (e.g. validity or confidence) of the example. How can this be implemented in Tensorflow, in particular when using `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the most common case where you call `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with `logits` of shape `[batch_size, num_classes]` and `labels` of shape `[batch_size]`, the function returns a tensor of shape `batch_size`. You can multiply this tensor with a weight tensor before reducing them to a single loss value:

```py
weights = tf.placeholder(name="loss_weights", shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)
loss_per_example = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(weights * loss_per_example)
```

Comment: When we specify the weights as a part of `tf.train.Example`, do we have to specify the weights as one hot encoded list or simply a list that matches the bboxes list in that image. Example: `'image/object/weight': dataset_util.float_list_feature(weights)`