# Tensorflow Estimator: training with weighted examples

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a model with Tensorflow `Estimator`, and my data is not balanced.  I want to correct for this by weighting each training example.

In raw Tensorflow one might do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867942/weighted-training-examples-in-tensorflow). Is there an easy way to do this in `Estimator`?  Perhaps building a custom `input_fn`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upweight a Category in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098951/upweight-a-category-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing classification. If so, use [`tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier#__init__):

> **weight_column**: A string or a `_NumericColumn` created by
>   `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` defining feature column representing
>   weights. It is used to down weight or boost examples during training.
>   It will be multiplied by the loss of the example. If it is a string,
>   it is used as a key to fetch weight tensor from the `features`. If it is
>   a `_NumericColumn`, raw tensor is fetched by key `weight_column.key`, then
>   `weight_column.normalizer_fn` is applied on it to get weight tensor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a custom estimator model, you should forward the class weight for each sample of your dataset as a feature to your `model_fn` and when defining the loss function op you can pass the class weight on `weight` parameter.

**Example:**

```
 tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(target, logits,weights=features['weight'])
```

Comment: Sadly the weights parameter is no longer available. However, the mathematics of cross entropy means that you get the same effect by changing the target value from 1.0, to a lower number to downweight an example or to a higher number to upweight it.

Comment: If you are using Keras and tf.Dataset API, you can specify the sample weight if your input_fn outputs a 3-value tuple -> (Input,Target,Weight)

Comment: Hi, Do you have any code example for tf2 to implent custom weights in a model_fn?