# Loss reduction in canned TF estimators

Tags: tensorflow, classification, minimize, loss

I use a TensorFlow canned estimator (`LinearClassifier`) to predict game actions from situations favourizing best scores. Scores are included in `train_data` and used as weight and passed as weight column in the estimator.

I know weight values are multiplicated with loss (MSE in this case) but I want to know if loss minimization is done or if I have to define optimizer as:

```
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1= 0.9,beta2=0.99, epsilon = 1e-08,use_locking=False).minimize(loss),
```

```
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1= 0.9,beta2=0.99, epsilon = 1e-08,use_locking=False),
                                    weight_column=weights,
#                                    dropout=0.1,
#                                    activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                    n_classes=10,
                                    label_vocabulary=Action_vocab,
                                    model_dir='./Models/ActionPlayerModel20/',
                                    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
                                    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=10))
```

Comment: @Stewart_R : "Not at all sure what you mean by". Described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098951/upweight-a-category). What about minimize operation ? Is loss reduction operation implemented in canned estimators ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: The canned estimator just takes the optimiser object and handles the minimise operation internally.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify this - I'd intended to convey that first time round but on rereading I could have been clearer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not at all sure what you mean by:

> I know weight values are multiplicated with loss

but the classifier line is correct as you have it. You should pass the Optimizer object into the classifier and not the `.minimize()` operation. The estimator will generate & handle the minimize operation internally.